# Symfony 2 api_caller in external class

Tags: symfony

In Symfony 2 I am using this bundle library (https://github.com/LeaseWeb/LswApiCallerBundle) to make API REQUEST.

This is the function to do it:

```
$this->get('api_caller')->call(new HttpPostJson($path, $object));
```

If I put the above function in the DefaultController it works.
But I would like to use that function in my external class without extend controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the moment you would register a new service in the service container.

In your bundle's Resources/config/services.yml, assuming you're using YAML

```
services:
    your_service:
        class:     Your\Bundle\Namespace\YourClassName
        arguments: ["@api_caller"]
```

Then in your external class

```
<?php

namespace Your\Bundle\Namespace;

use Lsw\ApiCallerBundle\Caller\LoggingApiCaller;
use Lsw\ApiCallerBundle\Call\HttpPostJson;

class YourClassName
{
    private $apiCaller;

    public function __construct(LoggingApiCaller $apiCaller)
    {
        $this->apiCaller = $apiCaller;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        $this->apiCaller->call(new HttpPostJson($path, $object));

        //....
    }
}
```

then in your controller

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function someAction()
    {
        $foo = $this->get('your_service');
        $foo->doSomething();
    }
}
```